# Adding WCS to ArcMap - Failed to open raster dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6, wcs

I would like to add the WCS of this dataset to ArcMap: 
https://hfrnet-tds.ucsd.edu/thredds/catalog/HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/catalog.html?dataset=HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR_US_West_Coast_500m_Resolution_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd

- I go to "Add Data"
- Select GIS Servers
- Select Add WCS Server
- Paste the
  WCS URL
  (https://hfrnet-tds.ucsd.edu/thredds/wcs/HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR_US_West_Coast_500m_Resolution_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities)

I see three grids available (latitudinal... surface_eastward..., surface_northward..) but when I try to add them to the map I get an error: "A selected item could not be added to the map Failed to open raster dataset"

How can I add this data to ArcMap?

Comment: the WCS URL is just `https://hfrnet-tds.ucsd.edu/thredds/wcs/HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR_US_West_Coast_500m_Resolution_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?`

Comment: I just tried this. I pasted the URL, clicked "Get Coverages," selected everything (3 items), clicked "OK," clicked "Add," selected the 3 items, clicked "Add," and still get the same message: "A selected item could not be added to the map Failed to open raster dataset" Did it work for you?

Comment: I get a similar message.  I can see that ArcMap sends a DescribeCoverage request, the WCS service responds but takes too long to return a complete document.  So this appears to be an issue with the WCS service, rather than ArcMap.

Comment: In QGIS I also get an error `2019-09-26T15:33:00     CRITICAL    Invalid Layer :`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is to do with a misconfiguration of the WCS service.

A DescribeCoverage request like below, tells us that the spatial reference system used by the coverage is `EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]`

> https://hfrnet-tds.ucsd.edu/thredds/wcs/HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR_US_West_Coast_500m_Resolution_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?service=WCS&request=DescribeCoverage&coverage=DOPx&version=1.0.0&

Gives us:

```
...
<domainSet>
  <spatialDomain>
    <EnvelopeWithTimePeriod srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
      <gml:pos dimension="2">-122.59346771240234 37.45548629760742</gml:pos>
      <gml:pos dimension="2">-122.0468978881836 38.13872528076172</gml:pos>
      <gml:timePosition>2011-10-01T00:00:00Z</gml:timePosition>
      <gml:timePosition>2019-09-26T09:00:00Z</gml:timePosition>
    </EnvelopeWithTimePeriod>
    <gml:RectifiedGrid srsName="EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]" dimension="2">
      <gml:limits>
        <gml:GridEnvelope>
          <gml:low>0 0</gml:low>
          <gml:high>105 152</gml:high>
        </gml:GridEnvelope>
      </gml:limits>
      <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
      <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
      <gml:origin>
        <gml:pos>-122.59346771240234 37.45548629760742</gml:pos>
      </gml:origin>
      <gml:offsetVector>0.005205426897321429 0.0</gml:offsetVector>
      <gml:offsetVector>0.0 0.004494993310225637</gml:offsetVector>
    </gml:RectifiedGrid>
  </spatialDomain>
...
```

As part of the operation of loading any WCS data ArcMap (and QGIS) look first at the GetCapabilities response, then a DescribeCoverage (for the selected coverages), and on the basis of the information in the DescribeCoverage response, make a GetCoverage request.

The problem is that `EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]` is not a known CRS.

A user selecting a CRS like crs:84 in their client will result in a request like:

> https://hfrnet-tds.ucsd.edu/thredds/wcs/HFR/USWC/500m/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR_US_West_Coast_500m_Resolution_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF_Float&COVERAGE=DOPx&TIME=2011-10-01T05:00:00Z&BBOX=-122.33565175758218402,37.79040736778109988,-122.30471384300375348,37.80380421058804075&CRS=OGC:CRS84&RESPONSE_CRS=OGC:CRS84&WIDTH=6&HEIGHT=3

Which gives an error along the lines of not a valid request expecting CRS of `EPSG:0 [Latitude_Longitude]`...